# Converting Object with arrays to arrays with arrays - *ngfor usage

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ngfor

I have a form that creates a array with data, then i place that array in a object in my firebase Datatime.

When i get the data from that object, the data in object with 2 arrays.

The problem is to use *ngfor i need the object to be an array with arrays in it. Is it possible?

How can i make it?

The object:

```
{adeus: Array(1), olaaaaa: Array(2)}
```

how i call it from firebase:

```
listSearch(){
    this.af.object("/list").query.once('value').then(data => {
      console.log(data.val() as string);
      this.teamsList = data.val() as string;
    });
  }
```

I get this error:

> core.js:4197 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

So i need a way to convert that object to an array with two arrays.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I not understand the solution that you want to made. But if you want to iterate into the properties of an object you can use Object.keys as follow

```
let object = { array1 : ['a','b'], array2 : ['c','d'] }
let arrayOfArrays = Object.keys(object).map(k => object[k])
```

the result will be

```
arrayOfArrays = [ ['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'] ]
```

Hope this can help you